# Add a 2nd source folder on a Gradle project which uses my Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I created a Gradle plugin which generates some Java code we want.

I tested my plugin on a test project and it worked perfectly, the files were correctly generated.

Now I have to apply my plugin on the project I work on, for doing this I added the following lines to the `build.gradle` of the project :

`buildscript {
    repositories {
        [...]
        mavenLocal()    <--
    }
    dependencies {
        [...]
        classpath 'my.plugin.path:app:1.0'  <-- the maven local path of my plugin
    }
}
apply plugin: 'myPlugin'  <--`

Then, the files that my plugin generates are placed into the `src` folder. In that case the project build correctly.

BUT, I would like to place the generated files into the `target` folder.

I tried two ways to resolve it :

1. Add a sourceSets block into the `build.gradle` like :

`sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'target/java']
        }
    }
}`

And when I try to `gradle build`, the `:compileDebugJavaWithJavac` task fail, because some code in the `src/main/java` folder needs the code I generate. But the code in the target folder seems to not be compiled.

2. Add the source folder through the plugin code

Here is my plugin class (in Groovy) :

```
import com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Task

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        def hasAppPlugin = project.plugins.hasPlugin AppPlugin

        project.afterEvaluate({
            def variants = hasAppPlugin ? project.android.applicationVariants : project.android.libraryVariants
            variants.all { variant ->
                def compileJavaTask = variant.javaCompile

                [...] // Adds tasks to the plugins

                compileJavaTask.source =  project.files("${project.rootDir}/target/java", output)

                compileJavaTask.dependsOn javaTask
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The 2 last lines should be enough, but I have the same problem than in case 1.

I actually have no idea why this doesn't work, do someone have any idea ?

Comment: I couldn't test answers this week end, this is for work but I'll keep an eye on your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+=` instead of `=` on the line :

```
compileJavaTask.source += project.files("${project.rootDir}/target/java", output)
```